# Leaflet Map is not loaded correctly

Tags: leaflet, loading

In my application I need coordinates. I would like to make it possible for a user to choose the coordinates using a map and a marker or to calculate them via an address. That works fine too.

But unfortunately, the map is not displayed correctly.

When I open the application it looks like the attached image.

[image]

Only on the top left is a small area visible. Then, when I open the web console to look for errors, the map suddenly pops up completely. An error is not given to me.

If I then move the map, it is again so that not all tiles are loaded.

Here is my code.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

var agosmsaddressmarkersurroundingdiv = document.querySelectorAll('.agomsaddressfindersurroundingdiv');



// For all fields [start]
    [].forEach.call(agosmsaddressmarkersurroundingdiv, function (element) {
        // Set the fields 
        // Todo Error Handling
        var buttons = element.getElementsByTagName('button');
        var addressbutton = buttons[0];
        var mapid = addressbutton.getAttribute('data-mapid');

        var inputs = element.getElementsByTagName('input');
        var lat = inputs[0];
        var lon = inputs[1];
        var address = inputs[2];
        var hiddenfield = inputs[3];

        // Write the value to the fields
        if (hiddenfield.value.split(',').length !== 2) {
            hiddenfield.value = '50.27,7.26,';
        }
        ;
        var hf = hiddenfield.value.split(',');

        lat.value = hf[0];

        lon.value = hf[1];

        // Set the map
        var map = L.map(mapid);
        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
        map.setView([lat.value, lon.value], 9);
        var marker = new L.marker([lat.value, lon.value], {draggable: 'true'}).addTo(map);
        marker.on('dragend', function (event) {
            var marker = event.target;
            var position = marker.getLatLng();
            marker.setLatLng(new L.LatLng(position.lat, position.lng), {draggable: 'true'});
            map.panTo(new L.LatLng(position.lat, position.lng));
            lat.value = position.lat;
            lon.value = position.lng;
            changeValue();
        });

        // Write the value to the hidden field if lat or lon is changed
        lat.onchange = function () {
            changeValue();
        };

        lon.onchange = function () {
            changeValue();
        };

        addressbutton.onclick = function () {
            var addressstring = address.value;
            var cords = function (results, suggest) {
                if (!suggest && results.length === 1) {
                    lat.value = results[0].lat;
                    lon.value = results[0].lon;
                    lon.onchange();
                    marker.setLatLng([results[0].lat, results[0].lon]);
                    map.panTo(new L.LatLng(results[0].lat, results[0].lon));
                } else if (results.length > 0) {
                    // Limit is fix set to 1 up to now
                } else {
                    Joomla.renderMessages({"error": [Joomla.JText._('PLG_AGOSMSADDRESSMARKER_ADDRESSE_ERROR') + addressstring + ' (Nominatim)']});
                }
            }
            var params = {
                q: addressstring,
                limit: 1,
                format: 'json',
                addressdetails: 1
            };
            getJSON("https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/", params, cords);
        }

        function changeValue() {
            hiddenfield.value = lat.value
                + ',' + lon.value;
        }
    }); // For all fields [end]
}, false);

function getJSON(url, params, callback) {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState !== 4) {
            return;
        }
        if (xmlHttp.status !== 200 && xmlHttp.status !== 304) {
            callback('');
            return;
        }
        callback(xmlHttp.response);
    };
    xmlHttp.open('GET', url + getParamString(params), true);
    xmlHttp.responseType = 'json';
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function getParamString(obj, existingUrl, uppercase) {
    var params = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        var key = encodeURIComponent(uppercase ? i.toUpperCase() : i);
        var value = obj[i];
        if (!L.Util.isArray(value)) {
            params.push(key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value));
        } else {
            for (var j = 0; j < value.length; j++) {
                params.push(key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value[j]));
            }
        }
    }
    return (!existingUrl || existingUrl.indexOf('?') === -1 ? '?' : '&') + params.join('&');
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem probably comes from the fact that seemingly you are doing the whole map thing inside event processing function. `setTimeout` function usually helps in such cases.

Comment: Need to have a map first then use setview to zoom to the new coordinates. Here is an example: http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/basic/addmarker.html right click view source to see my code.

Comment: Smells like a missing `invalidateSize()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762984/leaflet-map-not-displayed-properly-inside-tabbed-panel